# Validate a path

Tags: c#

Is there any way of validating if a path can be correct in .net or do I need to write something myself?

What I have is a string that is supposed to be a valid path such as:

```
\\server\shared\folder\file.ext
c:\folder\file.ext
.\folder\file.ext
\folder\file.ext
%appdata%\folder\file.ext
```

The path does not need to exist on the machine where this is run and the network does not need to be accessible, I'm only interested to see if the path could ever be valid.

Was thinking about splitting the path into filename and path and then using the Path.GetInvalidPathChars() and Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() arrays to check if the path contains invalid filenames which would at least be a start. But there may be better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following library which is part of NDepend: [NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](http://filedirectorypath.codeplex.com/) It has rich API for processing pathes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you define a valid set of regular expressions? I think we can define the patterns..

Comment: It may be possible to write a regex that covers any and all valid paths in a windows environment but it seems as if it would be very easy to miss an invalid path or worse by mistake mark some paths as invalid.

Comment: Why to make regex for invalid paths? Why not to make only for valid paths? All paths which doesn't conforms to this regex will be invalid..!!